# Does this color legend example only work for d3 v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, canvas, observablehq

Trying to copy over the code from: https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend?collection=@d3/d3-scale to make an actually nice looking sequential color legend. (haven't tried https://d3-legend.susielu.com/ but I don't like how it looks).

I copy over the legend function and the ramp function from the sample code. I get the error message:

> "ReferenceError: DOM is not defined".

I'm using d3 v4. I don't copy over the `d3 = require("d3@5")` line because I locally have the d3 file for v4, and when I try to use that line, I get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I understand that this line is just creating a canvas object but I can't find any information online of what the arguments mean for the `canvas` function.

I suspect that the issue might be that `DOM.canvas` is a d3 v5 function, but even if that's the case, there must be some equivalent way to do the same thing in v4.

Comment: Nothing to do with D3. That's just an [Observable](https://observablehq.com) feature (I added the tag accordingly). By the way, Observable was created by Mike Bostock, the same person who created D3.